# Class design in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, class, three.js

I'm trying to achieve some object oriented programming with JavaScript and Three.js.

I started to encapsulate the Scene with a class, as below, and I have the `update` function for animation in the class. This works fine, but I want to have another class with controls.

The `Controls` class also has an update function that should be called every tick of the Scene. So I created an array that holds function pointers to all possible update functions that are required to be called in `Scene.update`.

Such as this:

```
Scene = function() {
     ... // scene init etc.
     this.update_f = []; // My array of function pointers

     this.AddToUpdate = function(f) {
         this.update_f.push(f); // add function pointer
     };

     this.Animate = function() {
          requestAnimationFrame(this.Animate.bind(this));
          this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
          this.Update();
     };

     this.Update = function() {
       for(var i = 0; i < this.update_f.length; i++) {
           this.update_f[i]();
        }
     };
};
```

And some pseudo code of my Controls class:

```
Controls = function() {
     this.obj = new THREE.Object3D();
     ... // do stuff with obj
     this.update = function() {
          console.log(this.obj);
     }
};
```

And here is my main where I initialize everything:

```
 var scene = new Scene();
 var controls = new Controls();
 scene.AddToUpdate(controls.update()); // add function pointer
 scene.Animate();
```

Now to the actual problem. When the `scene.update()` calls the `controls.update()` function through the array (`scene.update_f`) it is called but the instantiated object seems not to be the object (instantiated in main as Controls) because `console.log(this.obj)` tells me "undefined".

So what am I doing wrong here? Please give me some hints on best practice for these things. I don't want to add everything to the Scene class since it might become huge if more stuff is added to it. I just want to jack-in other update functions to `Scene.update`.

Comment: Where is defined `controls.update` ?

Comment: Sorry, updated the pseudo-code.

Comment: Your code can't produce undefined in controls.update(). I'd suggest you take the time to build a working code reproducing your problem and ask again.

Comment: My actual code was so bloated of all tests so I just took out the parts I was relevant. But perhaps you can answer me on the last question if this approach is good or bad? Or what is the best-practice for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are multiple errors.

```
Controls = function() {
     this.obj = new THREE.Object3D();
     ... // do stuff with obj
     this.update() {
          console.log(this.obj);
    }
};
```

You don't assign the function to `Controls`. How about

```
this.update = function() {
    console.log(this.obj);
};
```

In your main you execute the update function and assign its return value to as parameter to `AddToUpdate`

```
var scene = new Scene();
var controls = new Controls();
scene.AddToUpdate(controls.update);
scene.Animate();
```

So if you want to pass in the function pointer, just remove the parenthesis.

Be aware, that if you pass an object's function to some other object, `this` will be the object to which you passed the function.

Comment: Would this solve the last issue?
scene.AddToUpdate(controls.update().bind(controls));

Comment: @NergalDimitri Dunno - i would pass in the whole object and just call its methods `scene.AddToUpdate(controls)` - and in `scene` `controlsParameter.update()`